# Splunk Event JSON to Table

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

In splunk I have an event that contains JSON data indicating the status of a list of feature toggles. It looks like this

```
2023-01-05 15:59:00,025 INFO  [com.example.FeatureToggleRepository] (executor-thread-4) {correlationId=efe2d0be-a4bc-4555-9ef3-cc640a107208, sampled=true, spanId=b200d532717a1a3b, traceId=020c59784f3f5624917ccf12defbc00a} {"featureToggles":[{"id":1,"updatedAt":"2023-01-05T14:59:00.010+00:00","createdAt":"2023-01-05T14:59:00.010+00:00","feature":"FEATURE_1","enabled":true},{"id":12,"updatedAt":"2023-01-05T14:52:46.614+00:00","createdAt":"2023-01-05T14:52:46.614+00:00","feature":"SOME_FEATURE","enabled":true}]}
```

How can I extract that and present it in a table with columns for id, feature and enabled?

I have tried countless examples, but just cant seem to get it to work.

Thank you.

EDIT:

This is what I wound up doing

```
...query...
| rex field=_raw max_match=0 "id\W+(?<id>\d+)"
| rex field=_raw max_match=0 "updatedAt\W+(?<updated>[^\"]+)"
| rex field=_raw max_match=0 "createdAt\W+(?<created>[^\"]+)"
| rex field=_raw max_match=0 "feature\W+(?<feature>[^\"]+)"
| rex field=_raw max_match=0 "enabled\W+(?<enabled>\w+)"
| eval an_event=mvzip(mvzip(mvzip(mvzip(id,updated,";"),created,";"),feature,";"),enabled,";")
| fields - id updated created feature enabled
| mvexpand an_event
| rex field=an_event "(?<id>[^;]+);(?<updated>[^;]+);(?<created>[^;]+);(?<feature>[^;]+);(?<enabled>.+)"
| table id feature enabled
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: what do your props.conf and transforms.conf look like for this sourcetype? JSON-inside-something-else does not get handled as "JSON" because it *isn't* "JSON"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *suspect* something like the following will work - but you're better off either getting this data as *proper* JSON (so Splunk handles it natively), or fixing your props.conf and transforms.conf

```
| rex field=_raw max_match=0 "id\W+(?<id>\d+)"
| rex field=_raw max_match=0 "updatedAt\W+(?<updated>[^\"]+)"
| rex field=_raw max_match=0 "createdAt\W+(?<created>[^\"]+)"
| rex field=_raw max_match=0 "feature\W+(?<feature>[^\"]+)"
| rex field=_raw max_match=0 "enabled\W+(?<enabled>\w+)"
```

Those will all be multivalue fields - so you *may* need to `mvzip` and then `mvexpand` them out (reextracting afterwards) like this:

```
| eval an_event=mvzip(mvzip(mvzip(mvzip(id,updated,";"),created,";"),feature,";"),enabled,";")
| fields - id updated created feature enabled
| mvexpand an_event
| rex field=an_event "(?<id>[^;]+);(?<updated>[^;]+);(?<created>[^;]+);(?<feature>[^;]+);(?<enabled>.+)"
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. I have been going crazy. I updated my question to include what I ended up doing

Answer (score 1):

@warren's answer is a good one.  Here's another method for extracting the fields.

````
``` Extract the JSON body ```
| rex "(?<json>\{\\\"featureToggles.*\})"
``` Parse the JSON ```
| spath input=json
``` Make the field name easier to manage ```
| rename featureToggles{}.* as *
| table id feature enabled
````

As @warren also said, you may need to use `mvzip` and `mvexpand` to break the fields into separate events.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated the question to show what I ended up doing.